# Algorithm for finding all critical paths

Tags: algorithm, graph

I need to create an algorithm that could find all the critical paths in a graph.

I have found the topological order of the nodes, calculated earliest end times and latest start times for each node.

Also I have found all critical nodes (i.e. the ones that are on a critical path).

The problem is putting it all together and actually printing out all these paths. If there is only 1 critical path in a graph, then I can deal with it but the issues start if there are multiple paths.

For example one node being part of several critical paths, multiple start nodes, multiple end nodes and so on. I have not managed to come up with an algorithm that could take all of these factors into account.

The output I am looking for is something like this (if a,b,c etc are all nodes):

- a->e
- a->c->f->i->j->k
- a->c->g
- l->e

It would be nice if someone could write a description of an algorithm that could find the paths from knowing critical nodes, topological order, etc. Or maybe also in C or java code.

EDIT:
Here is an example, which should provide the output I posted earlier. Critical paths are red, the values of each node are marked above or near it.
[image: Critical path]

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? An example graph, with the expected result, and a clear definition of critical nodes/paths?

Comment: Ok, I added the example graph for my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computation of latest start times nearly provides the critical path as well. You need to construct the results from the terminal nodes, and go backwards:

1. find all nodes that have the maximum earliest end time (t=11, nodes = {e,g,k})
2. for each of them, find all predecessors that have the locally maximum earliest end time.
    For e, both l and k have t=2, so you get l->e, a->e. For g, t=6, which is for node c,
    so you get c->g. For k, t=10, but only j has this as its end time, so you get j->k.
3. repeat until you reach the start node. l->e and a->e are already start nodes.
    c->g has the only predecessor a, so you get a->c->g. j->k has t=9, which is i's end time,
    so you get i->j->k.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your question entirely: what is a critical path? You'd might be helped by:
algorithm to calculate [Minimum Spanning Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) or [Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) - although you might probably already knew these algorithms.

Comment: "In project management, a critical path is the sequence of project network activities which add up to the longest overall duration." You can read more from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_path_method

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now you mention it, I vaguely remember being taught or explained me this.